# Extracting data from nested dictionaries in a loop

Tags: python, data-structures

> Given the dictionary, `nested_d`, save the medal count for the USA from all three Olympics in the dictionary to the list US_count
>
> ```
> nested_d = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19}, 'London':{'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22}, 'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}
> ```

```
US_count = []

for nested in nested_d:
    # print(nested)
    for country in nested_d[nested]:
            if "USA" in country:
                    US_count.append(country)

print(US_count)
```

I expect the output `[35,36,46]` but actual output is `['USA', 'USA', 'USA']`
please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this:

```
nested_d = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19}, 'London':{'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22}, 'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}
US_count = []

for nested in nested_d:
    for country in nested_d[nested]:
            if country=="USA":
                    US_count.append(nested_d[nested][country])

print(US_count)
```

output:

```
[35, 36, 46]
```

Comment: why do you need two loops?

Answer (score 2):

```
nested_d = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19}, 'London':{'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22}, 'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}

res = [nested_d[host]['USA'] for host in nested_d]

print(res)
```

output

```
[36, 46, 35]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should append `nested_d[nested][country]` to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

```
You just need to iterate through the nested dict and get the value of key USA.

nested_d = {
            'Beijing':{
                'China':51,
                'USA':36,
                'Russia':22,
                'Great Britain':19
            },
            'London':{
                    'USA':46,
                    'China':38,
                    'Great Britain':29,
                    'Russia':22
            },
            'Rio':{
                'USA':35,
                'Great Britain':22,
                'China':20,
                'Germany':13
            }
}

us_medals_count = []

for key, value in nested_d.items():
    if 'USA' in value.keys():
        us_medals_count.append(value['USA'])

print(us_medals_count)
```

Comment: replace `if value.has_key('USA'):` **LINE** with `if 'USA' in value.keys():` , as there is no `has_key()` method for dictionary.

Comment: it was in python2 but has been removed from python3. Yeah you are right.

Comment: Don’t use `has_key`; that’s a deprecated method and has been removed in Python 3. Use `key in dictionary`, a containment test.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the loop with:

```
for nested in nested_d:
    for country, value in nested_d[nested].items():
        if 'USA' in country:
            US_count.append(value)

print(US_count)
```

Output:

```
[36, 46, 35]
```

Comment: why do you need two loops?

Comment: @kuldeeprawani Because it's a nested dictionary

Comment: but you don't need to i have posted my answer you can refer that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
nested_d = {'Beijing':{'China':51, 'USA':36, 'Russia':22, 'Great Britain':19}, 'London':{'USA':46, 'China':38, 'Great Britain':29, 'Russia':22}, 'Rio':{'USA':35, 'Great Britain':22, 'China':20, 'Germany':13}}

US_count = []



for nested in nested_d:
    for country,medal in nested_d[nested].items() :
        if country == 'USA':
            US_count.append(medal)

print(US_count)
```

**Output**

```
[36, 46, 35]
```

**OR** 
You can try this:-

```
us_count = []

for key, value in nested_d.items():  #Here we getting dictionary in value.
    if 'USA' in value.keys():
        us_count.append(value['USA'])

print(us_count)
```

I hope it may help you

Comment: why do you need two loops

Comment: @kuldeeprawani First loop is used to get the `key` and `value` AND IN `value` we are getting `dictionary` again, so second loop is to get the key AND value of that dictionary.

Comment: @kuldeeprawani yes I have seen your solution, one can directly get a result by using only one loop also.

Comment: @kuldeeprawani I have updated my code you can see a solution with one `for` loop also.